# External API call from IOT edge gateway module

Tags: iot, azure-iot-hub, aws-iot

Is it possible to call an external API ( any simple API external to IOT edge gateway, eg : a hello world ping) from an IOT edge module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can. There is nothing stopping your module to call API's or set up external connections. As long as your host device allows it, you are good to go!